# How can I add a header in OnResultExecuted

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I need to add a header to the response.

The header value is based on the response body.

When I try to add the header I get an error: *'Headers are read-only, response has already started.'*

```
public class SecurityFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var body = await new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
        var objectResult = context.Result as ObjectResult;
        var resultValue = objectResult.Value;
        Console.WriteLine(resultValue);

        context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("foo", "bar");

        base.OnResultExecuted(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnResultExecuted` method is called **after the action result executes**. Response headers can't be set/modified if the result has been done.

You can use `OnActionExecuted` method which is called after the action executes, before the action result. Or use `OnResultExecuting` method which is called before the action result executes.

Here is a simple demo you could follow:

```
public class SecurityFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
    }
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {           
        var objectResult = context.Result as ObjectResult;
        var resultValue = objectResult.Value;
        Console.WriteLine(resultValue);
        context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("foo", "bar");
        base.OnActionExecuted(context);
    }        
}
```

Comment: That did the trick!
Thanks @Rena